# Navigation not staying contained within parent div when browser window resized

Tags: css, html

I have an ul of navigation links nested in a div which is in turn nested into a 'header' div. My header div also contains a banner image, which should display in the top left corner of the website, and next to the banner I want my navigation links, which contain drop down menus when moused over.

Right now I am floating the banner to the left, and the nav links are automatically displaying next to the banner at my desktops resolution. The problem with this method is that once I resize the browser window the nav links begin to wrap around the banner and it looks terrible. Ideally I want the banner and the nav links to stay on the same line no matter the resolution of the device my site is viewed on.

Here is a jfiddle with an example of how my site displays. When I view the site at my default resolution of 1920x1080 it displays fine, but when I resize it does some funky stuff.

```
<!--- header div containing banner image and navigation bar --->

<div class="header">
    <a href="index.php"><img id="banner" src="img/image.png" alt="Banner image displays here"></a>   
        <div id="w">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="ddmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">The Staff</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Donations</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Volunteering</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Housing</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Links</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
         </div>


 /* relevent css for header, banner image, and navigation */

body {font-size: 100%; line-height: 1; max-width: 100%; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

a:link, a:visited, a:active  {color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: #C0C0C0;  text-decoration: none;}

.header {width: 100%; margin:0;  background-color: #FFFFFF;  padding-bottom: 10px;  margin-bottom: 10px;}

#banner { float: left; max-width:100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}
#w { max-width:50%; background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; } 
#ddmenu {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8aa8bd;
}


#ddmenu li { display: inline-block; float: left; font-size: 1.00em;}

#ddmenu li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 4.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0000;

}
#ddmenu li:hover > a { color: #FFF; background-color: #FF0000;}

#ddmenu li:hover ul {display:  block;}


/*Fills gap between top level li and nested ul so that the above mouse hover pseudoclass   selecting ul works*/

#ddmenu > li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    background: transparent;
}

#ddmenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* tooltip arrow */
#ddmenu ul:after {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 8px;
 border-width: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #fff transparent; 

}

#ddmenu ul:before {
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
left: 4px;
border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;  
}

#ddmenu ul li { 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
font-size: 0.9em; 

}

#ddmenu ul li a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 6px 2px;
 line-height: 1.4em;

}
```

Comment: Don't see a link to JSFiddle in your post, but I [pasted your code in myself](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtyc6/)...

Comment: ah I got ahead of myself and forgot to link it, thanks http://jsfiddle.net/46andtool/7ZNWv/1/

Comment: I removed a lot of your styling because there is a lot of CSS to debug, but take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8P3pR/). I think it shows a simpler example of the effect you are going for and you may be able to work from the CSS.

Comment: so the header div doesnt need to be given a percentage width in order to automatically resize itself? thanks for the help!

Comment: I expanded my comment with some explanation and posted it as an answer if you want to accept it, since it seemed to solve your problem. :)

Comment: that worked exactly as I had hoped, I made the novice mistake of designing my site for the desktop first rather than mobile and just working my way up with media queries and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed a lot of your styling because there is a lot of CSS to debug, but take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8P3pR/). I think it shows a simpler example of the effect you are going for and you may be able to work from the CSS.

Here's a breakdown of the most important parts of the CSS:

- `.header ul { list-style-type: none; }`: don't show bullets
- `.header li { display: inline-block; }`: make the list items sit next to each other horizontally instead of stacking in a column like normal
- `.header ul ul li { display: block; }`: Not for submenus, though. Still want those in a stack.
- `.header ul ul { display: none; }`: Don't show the nested lists...
- `.header li:hover ul { display: block; }`: ...until we hover over the parent
- `.header li:hover ul { position: absolute; }`: binds to nearest non-statically positioned ancestor
- `.header li { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; }`: which is its parent thanks to this trickery. Remember to specify **top** and **left** even if you're not moving anywhere or certain browsers will ignore you.

The rest is just fluff to make it look a little better. Since you're using `inline-block` to take care of most of the effect, you get resizing and wrapping for free.